# Create a Chain of drop-down list that base on the input of the previous one form the database in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am using database to populate the dorpdown lis. now when i select the option from the first dynamic populated drom down list i want to use it to populate another dropdown list and based on that selection third dromdown list.

Here's the code i am working on,

```
<html>
<?php
    include './config.php';
?>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <SCRIPT>
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        $("#testcasedata").on("change", function() {
            $(".dropdown").hide();
            var value = $("#testcasedata").val();
            $("#dropdown" + value).show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="createTestCase.php">
         // This is the first dropdown list 
         // It will return testsuite_id in dropdownlist
        <?php
            $sqll="SELECT testsuite_id FROM assigned_testsuite_tester Where Tester_name = 'Pritesh'";
            echo "<select class='form-control' name='testsuite'>";
            echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
            foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['testsuite_id'].'">'.$row['testsuite_id'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  
    {
        //testsuite_id will be the input variable for the second dropdownlist
        // the second dropdown list will populate with testcase_id. 
        $testsuite = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'testsuite');
        echo $testsuite;
        if($testsuite != ''){
            $sqll="SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase Where testsuite_id = '$testsuite'";
            echo "<select  name='testcasedata' id='testcasedata' >";
            echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
            foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['Testcase_id'].'">'.$row['Testcase_id'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
        }

        // with use of test case id i am retrieving the Product_id
        $testcase = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'testcase');
            $sqll="SELECT Product_id FROM Testcase_master Where Testcase_id = '$testcase'";
            $productid='';
            foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                $productid = $row['Product_id'];
            } 


            //now product id must be the input for the third dropdownlist.
            if($productid != ''){
                $sqll="SELECT circle.circle_id,circle.Circle_name FROM circle INNER JOIN assigned_circle_product ON assigned_circle_product.`Product_id` = '$productid'";
                echo "<select class='dropdown' name='circledata' id='circledata'>";
                echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
                foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['Circle_id'].'">'.$row['Circle_name'].'</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

i was able to populate the first drop-down list and based on that populate the second drop-down list.but having problem for populating third one.
I was browsing through similar questions and find out that i need to use jquery/JavaScript to do that.I don't know that much about jquery but  have inserted code for that too but still having problem to populating the third drop down list.
I am stuck at this point.Please give me some guidance.

Comment: Could you explain, what Dropdown Lists you have (ID, Name) and which should do what? Its very hard to see the relations between these dropdowns. And please try to explain, which dropdown should trigger the certain events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery to fill multiple dropdown list from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414513/jquery-to-fill-multiple-dropdown-list-from-database)

Comment: i have edited the question and have appropriate add comments.

Comment: @david strachan i have view that question already and few others like that but it didn't help so, i have posted this question.

Comment: I am Sorry but link above the question is no were near this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been learning Javascript/Jquery and this is what i have done.
I don't know if it's a correct way or not. please look and tell me if i can do more to improve code.

First i have devided whole program into three seprate PHP files.

**1.Main PHP File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'footer.php';
    include './config.php';
    ?>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showCircle(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","GetProduct.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function product1(str) {
        str1 = document.getElementById("project");
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","GetTestcase.php?prod="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Add Circle to Product</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Select the circles where you want your product to test:
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <form action="circlrproduct.php" method="GET">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Project Name</label>
                                    <?php
                                        $sqll="SELECT Project_id,Project_title FROM project_master";
                                        echo "<select class='form-control' name='project' onchange='showCircle(this.value)'>";     
                                        echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
                                        foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                                        echo "<option value=$row[Project_id]>$row[Project_title]</option>";  
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";                                                                                                                                                
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div id="txtHint"></div>
                                        <!--<div id="txtHint1"></div>-->
                                    </div>                                                                                                                                                                               
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                                                  
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                
                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div>   
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

First i select the project from the drop down list and at at the time of selection a ajax call will be made to get the product.

2. **GetProduct.php**

   ```
   if(isset($_GET['q'])){
       $q = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET,'q');
   }else{
   //    header('Location:AddCircleToProduct.php');
   }
   $sql2="SELECT Product_id,Product_title FROM product_master where Project_id = '$q'";
   $support = $q;
   $result = $conn -> query($sql2);       
   echo "<label>Product Name</label>";
   echo "<select class='form-control' name='product' onchange='product1(this.value)'>";     
   echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           echo "<option value={$row['Product_id']}>{$row['Product_title']}</option>";  
   }
   echo "</select>";
   ```

   At the time of product selection one another call is made through Ajax to get the test case.

3.GET Test case

```
    if(isset($_GET['prod'])){
        $product = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'prod');
        $query = "select * from testcase_master where Product_id = '$product'";
        //echo $query;
       echo '<div class="panel-body"><div class="dataTable_wrapper"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example"">';
       echo '<thead><tr><th>SELECT</th><th>Testcase Id</th><th>Testcase Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Created by</th><th>Subscriber Type</th><th>Priority</th></tr></thead><tbody>'; 
        if($results = $conn -> query($query) or die(mysqli_errno($conn))){
            while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
                echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox[]\"  value=\"".$row['Testcase_id']."\" class='form-control'/></td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Testcase_id']}</td><td>{$row['Testcase_title']}</td><td>{$row['Testcase_desc']}</td><td>{$row['Created_by']}</td><td>{$row['Subscriber_type']}</td><td>{$row['Priority']}</td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
           echo '</tbody></table></div></div>';
        } else {
             echo 'ss' . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
     }
      else{
         echo'Sorry You cant access this page Directly.';
    }
    ?>
```

After getting the list of test case selection of checkbox is made.

**4.circledata.php**

```
    <?php
    include './config.php';
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['checkbox'])){
      if (is_array($_GET['checkbox'])) {
       foreach($_GET['checkbox'] as $value){
        $q1 = "INSERT INTO tmtool.assigned_circle_product (`Circle_id`, `Product_id`) VALUES ('.$value.','$_SESSION[prod]')";
        if($conn -> query($q1) == TRUE){
              echo "Data Entered successfully\n";
        } else {
            echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
      }
     } else {
      $value = $_GET['checkbox'];
      echo $value;
     }
    }        

   }

   ?>
```

And in the last file all the data are commited into the database.

Please tell me if anything i can do to improve my code.
Thank you.